# Turning an Integer into a Base 10/Decimal System format?

Tags: java, decimal, radix, greatest-common-divisor

As part of my Cryptography Module's CW, I need to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to calculate the Greatest Common Denominator, GCD, of two BigIntegers. I've done this, it's easy and I know my code works.

However, there's a further specification that:

> Compute the Extended Euclidian algorithm for the following inputs and ***provide (d, s, t) in decimal system format in a text file with one line per number.***

I'm assuming they're asking me to write a file with 3 lines, a line representing each of the outputs converted from an integer representation to a base 10 representation, ie:

> (1 x 100,000 (10^5)) + (2 x 10,000 (10^4)) + (6 x 1000 (10^3)) + (3 x 100 (10^2)) + (2 x 10 (10^1)) + (5 x 1) = 126,325

Is my interpretation correct? **What's the best way to go about doing this?**

Comment: is CW stand for classwork ?

Comment: Coursework* Should've clarified, I can always ask my lecturer or others on the course, but I wanted to check quickly if my understanding is correct, and whether there's a preferred way of doing what I believe needs done.